# Get first element of LinkedList<T>

Tags: c#, linked-list

I'm a beginner programmer and I have this problem in C#. The solution is probably easy, but that's not for me to decide.

I have this custom class that inherits LinkedList and I need a method to return first element and remove it from list.
Code:

```
class CustomClass : LinkedList<CustomElement>
{
    public CustomElement getFirstElement(){
        //here is the problem and I don't know how to solve it
        CustomElement ce = this.First;
        this.RemoveFirst();
        return first;
    }
}
```

Problem is that `this.First` returns LinkedListNode. I tried this:

```
LinkedListNode<CustomElement> first = this.First;
```

But then the return statement fails, because type of method is `CustomElement`.

Comment: Consider using a Queue, if you want to remove(Dequeue) the first element when you read it.

Comment: No idea why this has so many downvotes. Found it immediately through google and it contained exactly the information I needed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86397t7k.aspx), the `Value` property of `LinkedListNode<T>` can be used to access the value stored in the list item. Therefore, assign `CustomElement ce = this.First.Value;`.